# What are the risks of not validating user input in this web service?

Tags: python, web-services, security

I'm reviewing an data export web service which:

1. takes a file name as input (simply a name, not a full path)
2. concatenates a full path to the file using a directory string constant
3. zips the file
4. returns a url to the output zip file which is sitting in web accessible directory

If no validation is ever done on the input file name (e.g. *does the file exists*), what potential risks / vulnerabilities may the web service have to people with mal-intent?

Comment: **No** validation? How about zipping up the system password file? Does that sound sufficiently dangerous?

Comment: btw, the file name is not a full path, just a name.  The name is concatenated with a directory string on the server. Do you have a example / pseudo input string that may cause the vulnerability you mention?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @bcollins directory_path/../../../../../../../some_dir_under_root

Comment: Not sure why i got down-voted.  I think this question helps to highlight the problems associated with not validating user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say your `directory` string constant is `"/tmp/files"`

An attacker could provide `"../../etc/passwd"`

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath(directory + "../../etc/passwd")
'/etc/passwd'
```

You would, at the very least, want to strip the input down to the basename

```
>>> os.path.join("/tmp/files", os.path.basename("../../etc/passwd")
/tmp/files/passwd
```